# php, gd and style

Tags: php, gd

for example i have this html code:

```
<p><strong>Text text.</strong></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><span style="background-color: #ff0000;">Text text...</span></span></p>
```

Possible write this text with this style on the image (with php GD)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [`imagecolorallocate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) to set the red background color
- [`imagestring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) to write a string onto an image (there's an argument for font size)
- [`imageloadfont`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) to load a bold version of a font

Post another question if you've tried writing it with these functions and have a specific problem

Comment: Thanks, but i hade this text in one string.